# Why can I not add a second bounty to a question?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

If a question has a bounty on it by the asker, but I am also super interested in the answer, why can I not add a second bounty, using my own rep, to the same question?

I see in the rules (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) that:

`The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.`

Why do we have this policy?

Comment: Probably because it was easier ([YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt) and [KISS](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KeepItSimpleStupid)). Also, because one of the main-purposes of bounties is advertising, and one bounty works as well as two would there.

Comment: But I want to double the amount of advertising to make it much more lucrative that the question be answered...

Comment: put a bounty for more points then?

Comment: @Julldar If you had read, you would see that the bounty was put by the asker so  I cannot change their bounty. Moreover I think they put the maximum bounty, and I wanted to double it.

Comment: sorry, I did read diagonally and basically only read the part you highlighted.  In that case, I do understand your point, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It's the presence of the bounty that puts the question on the "featured" tab, where they are ordered by expiry date - with the ones that expire soonest appearing first in the list.

The amount is incidental to this process.

All the amount of the bounty possibly influences is whether people answer or not. Adding a concurrent bounty isn't really going to change that that much.

Comment: but, `the bounty influences is whether people answer or not` is EXACTLY the point of a bounty! If I double the bounty, I double the chance someone will work hard on it.

Comment: @Tommy - possibly. I was more certain that I meant to be in my answer.